# tcp server slow communcation

Tags: performance-tuning, networking

I am trying to use Mathematica as tcp server for computer vison, but I run into problem with speed. Mathematica recieves images from python and it takes very long time to accept the image, if I use C# to Python (full HD) everything works just fine. This is the code from Mathematica:

```
Port = 5005;
Ip = "127.0.0.1";
message = 0;
listener = "0";
outSocket = 0;

startSession[] := (
  listener = 
    SocketListen[{Ip, Port}, recieveMessage, 
     HandlerFunctionsKeys -> {"DataByteArray"}];
  )

getMessageLength[msg_] := (
  ImportByteArray[Part[msg, 1 ;; 4], "Integer32"][[1]]
  )

t = 0;
messageBuffer = {};
msgLenght = 0;

recieveMessage[x_] := Module[{sameLength},
  If[Length[messageBuffer] == 0, messageBuffer = x["DataByteArray"];
   msgLenght = getMessageLength[x["DataByteArray"]];
   t = AbsoluteTime[]; 
   Echo[msgLenght];
   ,
   messageBuffer = Join[messageBuffer, x["DataByteArray"]];
   ];

  sameLength = msgLenght == Length[messageBuffer];

  If[sameLength,
   messageBuffer = {};
   Echo[AbsoluteTime[] - t];
   ,
   Return[0];
   ];
  ]
startSession[]
```

and here Python:

```
import socket
import time
import struct

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

message = "x" * (1920*1080*3)

mess = struct.pack('i', (1920*1080*3 + 4) )
mess = mess + message
s.send(mess)
s.close()
```

The main problem is not join, even if I do not store recieved data it does not change the time much and is still around 9 seconds.

Do you have any idea how to speed it up? I need to get to times below 0.1 seconds per image. Python and Mathematica run on the same computer.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised when it turns out that this is indeed very slow. On the other hand the line `messageBuffer = Join[messageBuffer, x["DataByteArray"]]` sticks out as something that might be really slow. Have you tried how long your code could would run without that line (that is if you just discard the message content)? If that would be fast I think you should be able to speed up the code considerable...

Comment: Like I wrote in the question, if i discard all data (no Join) it does not have any real effect on the time

Comment: sorry, didn't see that. Then I'm afraid I have no idea why this is so slow...

Comment: I know this is old but did you find any solution? I am also facing simillar problem.